# What is a descriptor that means "quick at visually locating or identifying"?

Tags: single-word-requests

If someone could quickly find a word in a large block of text, or were really quick at *Where's Waldo?* books, what is a concise descriptor you could use to express that quality?

I used to think this was [**visual acuity**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/visual_acuity), but that doesn't seem to be the case:

> NOUN
>
> Sharpness of vision, measured by the ability to discern letters or numbers at a given distance according to a fixed standard.

Comment: How about _observant_, or _sharp-eyed_?

Comment: I think sharp-eyed nails it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A person who is [**sharp-eyed**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sharp-eyed)

> is very good at noticing things

-Cambridge Dictionary online

[Synonyms include](https://www.google.com/search?q=sharp-eyed%20synonyms&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b&gfe_rd=cr&ei=L2t5WPr_Ie_R8AeXqpbIBw):

> observant, perceptive, eagle-eyed, hawk-eyed,

A word which goes even further is

[**percipient**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/percipient?a=british)

> good at noticing and understanding things